# Can I run doxygen on a url/ online repository?

Tags: doxygen

I have a large project that I would like to be able to have a top level doxygen build with lots of smaller doxygen builds (connected through tagfiles). Would it be possible to run doxygen at the top level without having to checkout the entire project by running doxygen on a virtual subversion repository?

Comment: I don't know what you mean with "virtual subversion repository", so some explanation would be good. For doxygen to run it needs the sources / tagfiles (and embedded images etc.) to be accessible so some checkout is required.

Comment: It's just the repository stored online. I was hoping to be able to run doxygen with just a URL to the repo.

Comment: Interesting thought, but I think that it would required quite a few changes (e.g. in respect of how to open a file and copying a file). Also would the result be to placed online or can this be local? Did you try something?

Comment: I figured it would be outputted locally then would have to be checked in to the repo along with any other changes that had been made to the local checkout. I haven't done anything with it yet since I didn't know what doxygen files I would have to edit and I didn't want to accidentally break it for nothing.

Comment: I would not commit the results of a doxygen run into a repository, as it is derived information.